# Problem with circular references in Vue.js - but only in CodeSandbox

Tags: vue.js, circular-reference, codesandbox

I have a Vue.js application (m4ops), and am developing a public Vue.js package ([vfg-display-fields](https://github.com/PeterC66/vfg-display-fields)) to be part of it. As it is a tree structure, the package has a pair of components which are circular references.  I have resolved this using the methods in the [Vue.js Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components).

Within my vfg-display-fields package this works well using either method.  When I publish the package and import it into my main m4ops package it also works fine using either method.

The problem comes when I try to showcase the package within a CodeSandbox (see https://codesandbox.io/s/ykpj1jpxvv).

With the first suggested method I use

```
beforeCreate() {
  this.$options.components['vfg-display-fields'] = require('./DisplayFields.vue').default;
},
```

and in CodeSandbox I get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vfg-display-fields> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Using the second method

```
components: {
  'vfg-display-fields': () => import('./DisplayFields.vue'),
},
```

I get the error

```
proxyConsole.js:72 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function vfgDisplayFields() {
      return _promise.default.resolve().then(function () {
        return require("".concat(function () {
          return require('./DisplayFields.vue');
        }));
      });
    }
Reason: DependencyNotFoundError: Could not find dependency: 'function () {
          return require('.' relative to '/node_modules/vfg-display-fields/src/DisplayGroups.vue'
```

This is only my first package and I am feirly new to Vue.js. My package seems to work fine in its intended location (my m4ops application) but not within CodeSandbox. Is this my error or something within CodeSandbox?

Comment: It's problem of `vfg-display-fields`, because it's own codesandbox show the same error. Try to write him issue about that.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I am the author of `vfg-display-fields`, and that is why I raised this issue. Seeing as my code for `vfg-display-fields` works OK with my main application, I suspect that it might be a problem with CodeSandbox rather than my code.

Answer (score 0):

In `DisplayGroups.vue` you use component `vfg-display-fields` by custom element name, but that component has name `DisplayFields`.
Base on documentation about [Recursive Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components), name of component must be the same as used in `Vue.component(...)`.
In `src / DisplayFields.vue` you must write

```
export default {
  name: 'vfg-display-fields',
...
```

Or in `src / index.js` change name of component while register it

```
Vue.component('display-fields', DisplayFields);
```

and don't forget to change element name in `src / DisplayGroups.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <display-fields .../>
  </div>
</template>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I think I have altered the naming as you suggest but I still have the same issue.  The new version (0.0.5-d) works fine within my own application, but not in CodeSandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this helpful post](https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/1631#issuecomment-475332461) I realised the problem was that I had published my package as ES6 code, while also using `.vue` files. I should have transpiled them to ES5 for publishing.

There is so much more for me to learn.